# Set ServiceBehavior on channelfactory WCF Net.Pipe

Tags: c#, wcf, net.pipe

I am hosting a Net.Pipe WCF service from a forms application, which runs on a server for mostly internal calculations. To improve on this I was tasked with creating a Rest shell around this service so it becomes reachable from outside of the server. I managed to connect to this service with ease, but as soon as I drop it on the live server My rest shell can no longer connect, I tried debugging this, but the main error message that gets logged is:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal
>   error.  For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the serviceDebug configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

Thing is that I connect to this service from code and I cannot figure out how to either convert the way I connect to a service host so I can add the Service behavior or add the behavior to my channel factory.

```
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
ServiceDebugBehavior behavior = new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true };
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/IPCService");
ChannelFactoryfactory = new ChannelFactory<RadanWrapper.IRadanContract>(binding);

// This line doesn't work
factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior as IServiceBehavior);
_channel = factory.CreateChannel(ep);
```

So the question is either: How do I connect the behavior to the channel factory, or alternatively, how can I connect to this net.pipe service through service host. (I am still looking into the second options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I tried adding the behavior to the rest shell (connecting end), while it should have been added to the forms application (Hosting end) that was hosting the net.Pipe WCF

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(IPCService));
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);

// Create new behavior, remove any existing behaviors and add this new one.
var behavior = new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true };
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPCService), binding, "net.pipe://localhost/IPCService");
serviceHost.Open();
```

Good thing I now got an actually working error message, turns out I was missing a specific dll that didn't get build correctly during deployment to the server.